# VB.NET: Mark Points in Line Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts

I'm creating a Chart with Lines on it in VB.NET. Now I got multiple Values in one Line. I want to mark certain of these values with a little Circle (or a Sqare, nevermind).

How do I have to do this?

It should look right light this:

[image: A Sample of a Line with highlighted and non-highlighted Values]

How to Achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the Point's Marker does the Trick:

```
dataGridView1.Series(0).Points(0).MarkerStyle = DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Circle
dataGridView1.Series(0).Points(0).MarkerSize = 10
```